# Change character to Superscript using applescript and quarkxpress

Tags: applescript, superscript

I have a list of of houses (see blow) with different sizes stated in (m2), I would like to replace all those instances with m2 and "2" set in superscript.

**The list of houses:**

- R45m     HOUSE. Landmark property with panoramic views, 2000m2 on over 8
  200m2. web ref: 3036011
- R27.5m HOUSE. Ambassadorial 6 bedroomed home on over 5000m2 web ref:
  3137592.

**My script:**

```
tell application "QuarkXPress"
tell document 1
    tell story 1 of current box
        set xx to 2
        set character style of xx to superscript
        set text of every paragraph where it is "m2" to "m" & xx
    end tell
end tell
end tell
```

**I get the following error:**

*`Can’t set «class CHSS» of 2 to superscript.`*

Please help, not sure if I'm going about it the wrong way.
Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After pulling may hair out I managed to come up with a solution I hope this would help someone else.

**Alterations to the script below:**

```
tell application "QuarkXPress"
tell document 1
tell story 1 of current box

set xx to («data utxt006D» as Unicode text) & «data utxt00B2» as  Unicode text
set text of every paragraph where it is "m2" to xx

end tell
end tell
end tell
```